# In this case can I use @ to avoid useless isset()?

Tags: php

Basically I need to create a string with `$_GET['param']`, something like:

```
$myString = $_GET['param'] . 'abc';
```

When `$_GET['param']` isn't isset i am perfectly fine with `$myString` being just `='abc'`

- So I can do something like this:

  ```
  $myString = @$_GET['param'] . 'abc';
  ```
- Or use the standard way with isset:

  ```
  if (!isset($_GET['param']))
     $_GET['param'] = '';

  $myString = $_GET['param'] . 'abc';
  ```

In this case using the `@` suppresser is considering such a bad pratice?

Comment: In any web app, I tend not to use $_GET and $_POST etc raw - I'll either use a framework, and so won't ever access them directly, or at least I'll wrap them in a function - which does the `array_key_exists()` stuff for me.

Comment: It's noteworthy that "error suppression" is a misnomer for `@`. It actually only disables thier display, and only for the default error handler. The debug notices still get generated, thus might show up in the log. The cumbersome syntactic workaround with isset is meant to avoid that (arguably a workaround at the wrong place). Besides that the difference is a 3µs micro optimization difference.

Comment: Even if you set up a custom error handler you can detect and ignore the error coming from `@-stmt` by doing:   `if (error_reporting()==0)
   return true;` (that's what I do in my custom error handler) so that's not a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most elegant thing IMHO would be to wrap that in a nice getter function, something like:

```
function _getParam($param, $default = '') {
    if (!isset($_GET[$param]))
       return $default;
    return $_GET[$param];

}


$myString = _getParam('param').'abc';
```

---

yes123 note:
As dvir said having a getter function for input variables in your framework can be handy. But this `_getParam` suffers of this problem:

Let's see we make a typo in our code, we want to access `$_GET['param']` and istead of it we type:

```
_getParam('parm')
```

Our code will work without generting any problems and we will have hard time finding the error.

So I thought we could modify the function presented to something like:

```
function _get() {
  $key = func_get_arg(0);

  if (func_num_args()==2) {
    if (!isset($_GET[$key]))
      return func_get_arg(1);  
  }

  return $_GET[$key];
}
```

This ensures that when we typo it with `_get('parm')` we will get a notice throwed normally. But when we use it with 2 param we get out default value:

```
_get('param','myDefaultValue');
```

Comment: that's not that bad... but you need to consider something like $_GET['arr']['key'] that makes stuff harder

Comment: And this basically does the same thing of @$_GET['param'] with 5 lines more of code.. so I don't think it's a good option

Comment: it's also a shorthand for defining a default value, plus you can add validators and converters inside it. virtually every web framework has some function like that and doesn't access $_GET directly.

Comment: @yes123 Creating a wrapper function instead of suppressing errors an notices isn't 'basically the same thing'.

Comment: I thought would could be wrong with this function, and finally I got it and a solution for it. I will edit this answer (I think it's ok for dvir volk)

Comment: @yes123 your function is fine, of course a function like that will be more complex, I was just showing the general idea. thanks for your addition.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using `@` like this:

```
$myString = ( isset($_GET['param']) ? $_GET['param'] : '' ) . 'abc';
```

---

> In this case using the @ suppresser is considering such a bad pratice?

Generally from the developer perspective it is good idea to avoid using `@` operator because it may hide errors that may be useful when debugging a particular problem. Other than that, it is very slow and for that reason, in the future version of PHP, `@` [won't be supported in `ini_set` calls](http://php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#changes-to-the-shut-up-operator-that-disallow-ini-set).

Comment: You mean: `$myString = isset($_GET['param']) ? $_GET['param'] . 'abc' : 'abc';` The OP wanted `abc` concatenated onto the get param

Comment: That `isset` example will suppress a possible debug notice. Thus doesn't align your explanation. The microoptimization meme is also redundant. (It's the notice generation, not the display suppression which incurs a slowdown. Measuring it is still a bit pointless, unless it's located in a loop.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not extremely elegant in my opinion (although it *is* short). I think the worst thing you have going here may be writing to the `$_GET` superglobal directly in your "standard" approach.

```
if (!isset($_GET['param'])) $_GET['param'] = '';
```

Maybe I'm being paranoid, but another unrelated script could run afterwards that checks for `isset($_GET['param'])`, and now it will return `TRUE` because you injected `''` into it.

So, yes - you can safely use error suppression here (there's not much you're going to miss), but there's no reason to avoid `isset()` either:

```
$myString = isset($_GET['param']) ? $_GET['param'] : '' . 'abc';
```